# Подскажите почему срабатывает единожды, на второй раз не хочет

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.run').click(function(){
      var $mgTop = $('.itmFirst').css('margin-top');
      if($mgTop<'100px'){ 
         $('.itmFirst').animate({marginTop:'+=30px'},1000,function(){});
      };
    });
```

Comment: `$mgTop<'100px'` замените на `$mgTop<100`

Comment: И тут `marginTop:'+=30px'` возможно не все у вас правильно с суммированием строки.

Comment: @Visman так не срабатывает даже на первый раз, а  из `marginTop:'+=30px'` по сути все правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример работы http://jsfiddle.net/szpayf30/

```
$('.run').click(function(){
  var mgTop = $('.itmFirst').css('margin-top').replace("px", "");
  if(mgTop<100){ 
     $('.itmFirst').animate({marginTop:'+=30px'},1000,function(){});
  };
});
```

Из строки свойства нужно удалить подстроку `px`, чтобы в строке осталось только число. И дальше в условии сравнивать с числом, а не со строкой.

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает:)